# UpdateCursor only updating last row

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, cursor

I am working with ArcMap 10.2. In the following code, I have a function, build_dictionary, that builds a dictionary that will be used to populate a field within another layer. With the second function, update_points, I am trying to use an UpdateCursor to iterate through each feature and if that feautre's OBJECTID is a key within the dictionary, populate a field called "RoutingStreetExtKey" with that key's value.

I have verified that the build_dictionary function works properly with an "AddMessage" (and therefore omitted the code). I return the dictionary in order to use it with the next function.

The problem occurs with the update_points function. As the script runs, I can see it iterate through the point layer, however it only updates the last feature. All other features have nothing written to the "RoutingStreetExtKey" field except the very last point feature. The last feauture is populated with the correct value.

I am concerned that I may not be passing the dictionary correctly from build_dictionary to update_points. Furthermore, is there something else I need to add to the body of UpdateCursor to ensure all features are being updated?

```
import arcpy
point_layer = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
street_layer = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

def build_dictionary():
    #Code...
    arcpy.AddMessage(ext_key_dict)
    return ext_key_dict

def update_points(passed_dict):
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(point_layer, ["OBJECTID", "RoutingStreetExtKey"]) as cursor_update:
        for new_row in cursor_update:
            obj_id = new_row[0]
            if obj_id in passed_dict:
                new_row[1] = passed_dict[obj_id]
                cursor_update.updateRow(new_row)
def main():
    update_points(build_dictionary())

main()
```

Comment: try running it in an edit session http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/editor.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's only running on the last row, it might have gotten selected somewhere else in the process, so it might be worth trying:

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(point_layer, "CLEAR_SELECTION")
```

right before you set up the `UpdateCursor`.

Comment: I made this change, but it's still only updating the last feature

Comment: Can you return some keys for known object ids in your AddMessage?

Comment: Also could the last row be selected?

Comment: Yes, I can return keys for known objects. I have verified that the last row is not selected.

Comment: Type mismatch? Your keys are strings but the OIDs are integers? I can't think of much else other than to throw in some print statements.

Comment: I added a print statement immediately under "if obj_id in passed_dict:" to print "passed_dict[obj_id]" and it only returns the value of the key pertaining to the last row. Something is causing it to skip over every feature until the last...

Comment: The clear_selection before the cursor did the trick. Thank you so much Marc.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is in the below line I believe

```
if obj_id in passed_dict[obj_id]:
```

You're checking if the value `obj_id` is in the returned value of your dictionary for `obj_id`. If you want to see if the key `obj_id` is in the dictionary you need to use the following line:

```
if obj_id in passed_dict:
```

Comment: I've made this change, but it is still only updating the last feature